# Jquery FAQ toogle with "dd" and "dt", click to close the answers

Tags: jquery

When I click on the question the answer comes up, I click back on the question the answer hides. What I was looking for was to insert a close text link at the end of the answer that would close the answer. Can you please help me?
Here is the script I use now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $('.faq dd').hide();
        $('.faq dt').click(function(){
          $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, I wanted the questions to look like links and when on mouseover the cursor should appear instead of the "I".

Comment: well to be exact, i voted your question and you accepted my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your working code

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.faq dd').hide(); 

    $('.faq dt').click(function(){ 
            $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('slow'); 
        });

    $('a.close').click(function (){ $(this).parent('dd').slideUp('slow'); });
 }); 
</script> 

<dl class="faq">
<span style="font-size: 14px; ">
<span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; ">
    <dt><span style="color: rgb(10, 171, 253); ">Question?</dt>

    <dd>Answer.<a class="close" href="#">Close Text</a></dd> 
</span>
</span>
</dl>
```

Comment: I am using this now but the whole faq doesn't work. Thank you. 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {          
$('.faq dd').hide();
$('.faq dt').click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
$('a.close').click(function (){ $(this).parent('dt').slideUp('slow'); })
    });

</script>

Comment: The faq got restored but the "close" link doesn't close the answer. Am I doing something wrong? Here is the script:
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {          
$('.faq dd').hide();
$('.faq dt').click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
$('a.close').click(function (){ $(this).parent('dt').slideUp('slow');
 });
    });
</script>
Tried one more }); to the above but the "close" doesn't work.Thanks for your patience.

Comment: <dl class="faq"><span style="font-size: 14px; "><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; ">
<dt><span style="color: rgb(10, 171, 253); ">Question?</dt>
<dd>Answer.<a class="close" href="#">Close Text</a></dd>
</dl> Thank you.

Comment: @user658044 change dt to dd and vice versa

Comment: I thought that dt was the question and dd was the answer. This is how it is set up in the java. So, do I change it only in the body?

Comment: @user658044 you should have updated your question with html code. But it's okay ... i will change the answer. But Make you sure accept my answer after that.

Comment: YESSS! Thank you very much to both of you. How do I vote you up?

Comment: I appreciated it very much. It's perfect.

Comment: @user658044 you cannot vote me up. you require 15 reputation point to vote up. You can accept my answer by clicking on the tick at left corner of my answer. And welcome to StackOver Flow.

Comment: Did it. You were both very helpful. I voted your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

#### jQuery

```
$('.faq dd').hide();
$('<span>close</span>').hide().appendTo('.faq dt');
$('.faq dt').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
});
```

#### CSS

```
.faq dt {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PZMSR/).

Comment: Thank you but what do I put in the body to add the "Close" link to close the answer?

Comment: I realized that just now :) How do I make it appear at the end of the answer instead of the beginning? Also, not the "close" and neither the questions appear like links. Sorry I am trying hard to understand jquery.
I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: @user Change the `appendTo('.faq dt')` to `appendTo('.faq dd')`. It won't appear as a link, because it isn't a link. You can make it look anything with CSS. Personally, I would put an `a` within the `dt` and link it to `#answer-2` which is an `id` you place on each `dd` element.